# Conda environment, but packages installed directly into the local python when python version is not specified upon creation. Normal behavior?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

so I've been using conda environments for a while. Today I accidently created a new conda environment without specifying the python version (so just

```
conda create -n myNewEnv
```

). I assumed that this will use my global python (3.11 if that matters) and indeed it did. But then when I activated this environment and started installing packages, I noticed that packages are directly installed into the global python directory. And when I went to the Anaconda directory to check this newly created environment, this conda environment (*myNewEnv*), unlike other envs I created, only has a *conda-meta* file and a *.nonadmin* file, which again is expected because no new python version is downloaded and installed.

The thing that interests (or rather, confuses) me is that the fact entering this virtual environment does not seem to provide the isolation from the global python which I assumed was the primary goal of having virtual environments (since packages are installed directly into the global copy). If so, I assumed this is not the correct usage of using a virtual environment and should be discouraged. But the official conda documentation[https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html] does not seem to mention that this should not be done in the first place, as their very first step in the "Creating an environment with commands" section demonstrates this. I am not saying the folks making conda are at wrong here, but rather,** I am just wondering is there anything I am missing here? Is there a usage of such environment which provides no isolation? Or am I misunderstanding something entirely?**

Thanks!